# How To Identify Which Button, Of Many, Triggered Single Storyboard Segue

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have 77 buttons on one view. These 77 buttons are in a collection outlet. The buttons are wired to trigger the same `segue`. The `segue` presents a `detailViewController` with information passed to it from the button. I need to know what button triggered the segue so that I know what data to pass to the detail controller.

I set the tag in the viewDidLoad method:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()

    var count = 0

    for item in buttonOutlets {

        item.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0
        item.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
        item.tag = count
        item.layer.borderColor = UIColor.yellowColor().CGColor
        item.addTarget(self, action: Selector("handleButtonPress"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

        count = count + 1
        println(item.tag)   // prints correct tag numbers

    }

    self.fetchAllObjects()

}
```

This is my `prepareForSegue`:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var upcoming: itemDetail = segue.destinationViewController as! itemDetail

if (segue.identifier == "loadDetailView") {

println(buttonOutlets[1].tag) // prints correct tag number

    let objectPlace = sender?.tag
    upcoming.parseObject = collectionObjects[objectPlace!] as? PFObject
}
```

Comment: Your approach using `sender.tag` looks correct - why isn't this working?

Comment: By the way, your `itemDetail` class name should start with a capital I - `ItemDetail` - by convention class names start with a capital and variables with a lower case letter.

Comment: sender.tag should work, are you setting the tags correctly?

Comment: What was the error or how it didn't work?

Comment: @sikhapol The error is: `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. I can println the `sender` object, it returns `<projectY.YellowController: 0x7fa5a31349d0>`. But I can't figure out how to access its properties.

Comment: I think `sender` is not actually a `UIButton`. What's the code for your `handleButtonPress`?

Comment: Okay, saw your answer. Congrat man. :)

Comment: @sikhapol You were right on it, it was in the handler. Thanks for taking a look :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer lies in `item.addTarget.` The action selector calls `handleButtonPress`. My original button press handler was:

```
func handleButtonPress(sender: UIButton) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loadDetailView", sender: self)        
}
```

What I was missing was `sender: sender`:

```
func handleButtonPress(sender: UIButton) {      
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loadDetailView", sender: sender)     
}
```

Then add a colon to `handleButtonPress` call:

```
 item.addTarget(self, action: Selector("handleButtonPress:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```